# "Server.ScriptTimeout" in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, timeout

In previous version of ASP.NET we could use "Server.ScriptTimeout" in controllers t ospecify timeout. How can it be done now in ASP.NET Core?

For example, I know that my page will require around 3-4 minutes to be run.  Is it possible to avoid timeouts?

Comment: How are you hosting you app? IIS?

Comment: yes, we host using IIS. Does it matter?

Comment: In my case it does. I have some action from my ASP.Net Core controller that are quite long, so I'm setting the timeout value in the web.config file that is consumed by IIS to let it know that it shouldn't timeout. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097433/request-timeout-from-asp-net-core-app-on-iis/43098493#43098493 Would it do the job in your case? It's not setting the value on a particular action of a particular controller though.