# ASP.NET CORE settimeout in json file

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core

i'm getting 502.3 error from my asp.net core application [long requests] and from answers: [Timeouts with long running ASP.NET MVC Core Controller HTTPPost Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474309/timeouts-with-long-running-asp-net-mvc-core-controller-httppost-method/38507709#38507709)
and [Request timeout from ASP.NET Core app on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097433/request-timeout-from-asp-net-core-app-on-iis)
i see that i need to extend timeouts but every answer contains setting timeouts in webconfig xml file and i'm using json file for my configuration.

```
    {
  "AppConfig": {
    "Name": "...",
    "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;User Id=root;Password=....;Database=....",
  }
```

I also have a launchSettings.json

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53573/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "SPS.Services": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    }
  }
}
```

How should equivalent look like from xml:

```
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
```

and where should i put it?

I'm using AspNetCore 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app "behind" IIS (you do, according to launchSettings), then you must make sure all items in chain (IIS, IIS/AspNetCore module that calls Kestrel and Kestrel itself) are not kill long-running requests.

Kestrel does [not have any request timeouts](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/485), nothing to configure.

For configuring IIS-related stuff, you should still use `web.config`, because IIS knows nothing about your json files. So feel free to create and modify `web.config` file using links you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the only way to solve it was creating a web.config file for my application. So I now have the appsettings.json plus the web.config.